# Get the last value of dataframe's column with indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the last value of column named "mass".

```
df = pd.read_csv('0000.csv', names=["chi", "mass"])
df_1 = pd.read_csv('0001.csv', names=['chi', 'mass'])
x=df['mass'][-1]

print(x)
```

And it raised error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 22, in <module>
    df2=df['mass'][-1]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 557, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1790, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3204)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2903)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3843)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 303, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6525)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 309, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6463)
KeyError: -1
```

However, I did succeed for the first value using `df['mass'][0]`. Why it does not work for index "-1"? I know there are alternative methods like using `iloc` `iat` `values`. But I just think `df['mass'][0]` would be the simplest one if it works.

Comment: `df['mass']` returns a Series so further selection with `[]` is a label based selection of the index. Your index **does not** have the label `-1` so you get that error. You want **array index** based selection to choose the last value with `-1`, which is accomplished with `iloc`: `df['mass'].iloc[-1]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's my lack of knowledge in pandas.

Comment: And just for completeness, the only reason `df['mass'][0]` works is because the default is for pandas to create a DataFrame with a RangeIndex starting from `0` so `0` happens to be the label of the first row. But had your index been `['a', 'b', 'c', ...]`  `df['mass'][0]` would encounter the same issue, while `df['mass'].iloc[0]` will succeed in selecting the first value.